# Segue won't show the ViewController when pressed

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, firebase

I currently have a `ViewController` with *prototype cells* in a `UITable View`. The `cells` currently display content from a *Firebase DB* when loaded. What I would like to do is when a `cell` is pressed more information is shown from the *Firebase DB*. However, I currently cannot get the `segue` to *push* to the `ViewController` from the `cell`. What should I do so this would work?

Image of my *Storyboard*--

[image]

Comment: What is the exact error that you are getting?

Comment: @TusharSharma I'm not getting any errors, that's the thing. I really don't know how to debug this issue.

Comment: have you pushed your view controller in which you have a table view with navigation controller.??

Comment: http://www.codingexplorer.com/segue-uitableviewcell-taps-swift/. CHECK THIS URL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found the solution to this. The issue was fairly simple actually. All I had to so was change the selection setting within the table view attributes from 'No Selection' to 'Single Selection'.

Answer (score 0):

These are two pieces of code that will help. For swift:

```
@IBAction func showEntries(_ sender: Any) {
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: <sequeId>, sender: nil)
}
```

and a button with the action wrapping this.

For Objective C, you can perform the segue like so.

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showEditor" sender:self];
```

Create the action by CTRL and dragging the button or cell into the corresponding code file, select action and name it.
[image]

Comment: Adding a button wouldn't look visually pleasing as Firebase content loads about 2 seconds after the button appears on the screen.

Comment: Opate buttons are an option, the answer above looks like it will work by selecting the row.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell, but from the screenshot, it looks like the segue goes from controller to controller, rather than cell to controller. If you'd like to do it like this, then you need to give the segue an identifier (in the right panel of your screenshot) and then override the delegate method

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "yourIdentifier", sender: self)
}
```

OR (if you don't feel like going to all this trouble)...in the storyboard, drag the segue from the **cell** to the view controller you want to push, rather than from controller to controller.

For example,

[image]

Notice how when the segue is selected, only the cell is outlined in blue, rather than the entire view controller.

Comment: Thanks, however selecting the cell itself does not work either and adding your piece of code doesn't change anything from before.

Comment: Hm...this might be a stupid question, but are the cells selectable? (Including making sure the cell's "Selection" option in the storyboard isn't set to "None".) And the cell's reuse identifier is properly set?

Comment: Also, I just noticed the segue type is show detail. Are you on an iPhone? Show detail is intended for use in split view controllers ("show this view in the detail pane of the split view"). If you're looking to just push a view controller onto a navigation stack, the type should be "Show (e.g. Push)".

Comment: Thanks again for your help as I tried both but nothing worked. Is there anything I can provide that may help figure out this issue?

Comment: Could you provide the code for the table view controller's class? I understand if not. Everything else in the storyboard looks ok to me.

Comment: Wow, I'm stumped. I pasted that into a blank project with a couple view controllers inside a navigation controller and it worked fine (had to comment out all the Firebase/custom cell stuff, but at a basic level it should be the same). Super unhelpful, I know...sorry :/

Comment: I didn't add anything suggested in the paste, that may be why

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is that some subview or gesture recognizer in the cell is interfering with the touch events by intercepting and handling them instead. Although that still doesn't make total sense to me. The labels and images shouldn't interfere with this. A text view could potentially (unless "user interaction enabled" is unchecked) - but even then you would still be able to select the cell if you tapped outside of the textview. Upvoted the question because now I'm curious what the answer is too!

Answer (score 0):

It's because cells are dynamic, so you can't assign an event handler from cell to uiviewcontroller. Instead you should make the segue inside your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method and push it from there. If you want to see the segue inside the storyboard nevertheless, then you can also ctrl+drag from viewcontroller1 to viewcontroller2 to make a new segue. Then select the segue and give it a Storyboard id. After That you can call `self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "yourIdentifier")`

Comment: I set the segue and the code where you said but the ViewController loads as soon as the cell loads. When I press back I am brought back to the cell and unable to press it again.